# Passar dados de uma tela a outra no Flutter com FireStore

Tags: flutter

preciso de um help gigantesco, estou tendo uma grande dificuldade em passar os dados de uma tela a outra no Flutter, estou utilizando o FireBase com o FireStore em um stream, porém não sei o que coloco no Navigator, e como fazer as variáveis para a segunda tela pegar os dados da primeira...
Socorro!

Preciso passar os dados da **ProductList** para a **ProductScreen**....

Link Github acaso queiram analisar https://github.com/alexandrechoske/BigTudoStore_Flutter

Tetei realizar assim porém ele não está reconhecendo na ProductScreen..

```
class ProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  ProductScreen({this.ref, this.descr}); /* Esse é o creator que vai receber os dados */
  final String ref;
  final String descr;

  @override
  _ProductScreenState createState() => _ProductScreenState();
}

class _ProductScreenState extends State<ProductScreen> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(descr)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

e no onTap:

```
onTap: () {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductScreen(ref: snapshot["ref"], descr: snapshot["descr"])));},
```

Porém ele acusa um erro de Undefined name 'descr' na ProductScreen.

Tks!!

Comment: E ai beleza? Coloca na sua pergunta o que você já fez para tentar passar os dados entre as telas, é só você [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/421150/edit) sua pergunta e colocar... Não utilize apenas links, pois um dia você pode tirar seu fonte daí!

Comment: Desculpe...ma já tentei tantas coisas que até não iria saber descrever aqui hehehe por isso achei que postar o código seria mais relevante para a situação....

Comment: Sim, o código é relevante, mas coloque um exemplo como da minha resposta, assim sua pergunta não será fechada e conseguiremos te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não colocou o que já tentou em sua pergunta, vou fazer um exemplo meio por cima para que você entenda.

Modifique a sua classe ProductScreen da seguinte forma:

> Se você utilizar o StatelessWidget

```
class ProductScreen statelessWidget{
  ProductScreen({this.nome, this.preco}); /* Esse é o creator que vai receber os dados */
  final String nome;
  final double preco;

  /* Substituir aqui com a sua programação normal*/
  Widget build(BuildCOntext context){
    return Coloumn(
      children: <Widget> [
        Text(nome),
        Text(preco.toString())
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

> Se você utilizar o StatefulWidget

```
class ProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  ProductScreen({this.ref, this.descr}); /* Esse é o creator que vai receber os dados */
  final String ref;
  final String descr;

  @override
  _ProductScreenState createState() => _ProductScreenState();
}

class _ProductScreenState extends State<ProductScreen>{
  /* Substituir aqui com a sua programação normal*/
  Widget build(BuildCOntext context){
    return Coloumn(
      children: <Widget> [
        Text(widget.nome),
        Text(widget.preco.toString())
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

No `onTap()` do seu item da lista, faça assim:

```
var navigation = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductScreen(nome: document["nome"], preco: document["preco"])));
```

**Como aparentemente você está começando com Flutter, te recomendo estudar antes algumas coisas básicas da linguagem!**

Você pode ler um pouco mais aqui [Send data to a new screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data).

Comment: Tks Matheus, vou fazer um teste assim!
Pelo que me lembro desse jeito ainda não testei, tinha feito algo similar porém ele apresentava um erro quando colocava no navigator com [].

**"The operator '[]' isnt defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'.

Try defining the operador '[]'.**

Comment: Esse é o ponto a qual me refiro para que edite sua pergunta e coloque alguma coisa que tentou já, assim podemos te auxiliar melhor.

Comment: @Choske leia o meu comentário, eu lhe aconselhei **EDITAR** a sua pergunta, não é legal colocar código aqui nos comentários, se você der uma olhada logo abaixo da sua pergunta vai encontrar um texto [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/421150/edit). (Pode editar pelo link que deixei aqui tbm no comentário)

Comment: Editei....mas parece que ficou meio bugado aqui no stack na hora que colei o código ali :(

Comment: @Choske verifique minha respsota novamente, fiz alguns ajustes, aplique para o seu caso.

Comment: capaz que era só colocar esse widget :(...obrigado Matheus, desculpa pela ignorância, te adicionei no Linkedin...obrigado mesmo :)